# Put a block quote in a figure caption with centered subfloat captions

Tags: subfloats, alignment, quotation

I'm trying to put a block quote in a caption like so,

[image: Correctly formatted]

My MCVE creates the correct formatting, but raises an error on line 23

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

Here's my MCVE

```
\documentclass{article}
%Packages for example image and text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \subfloat[Image A]{
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  }
  \subfloat[Image B]{
 \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  }
   \caption{ A quote follows this text:
     \begin{quote}
       \lipsum[3]
     \end{quote}
     Insightful and important stuff about the figure.}
     \label{mylabel}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried the solution from this question: [Block quote in figure caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100449/block-quote-in-figure-caption) but the subfloat captions become aligned left.

[image: Captions are aligned left instead of centered]

I need to use `subfig` or `subfigure` because my journal template is not compatible with `subcaption`

**How can I keep the subfloat captions centered?**

Comment: Did you check whether it is compatible with the  `floatrow` package, ans its `subfloatrow` environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own quote style without any other package. The only trick is to be able to put multiple lines into the caption environment (See the `caption` manual, end of page #13}.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}
%Packages for example image and text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}    

\newcommand{\quoteincaption}[1]{% build your own style!!
    {\medskip\hfill\parbox{0.7\linewidth}{\emph{\textquotedblleft#1\textquotedblright}}\hfill\medskip}  
}

\begin{document}        

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \subfloat[Image A]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        }
        \subfloat[Image B]{%
            \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        }
        %%  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101599/161015
            \caption[]{A quote follows this text:   
                                                
                \quoteincaption{\lipsum[3]}
                                        
            Insightful and important stuff about the figure.
                    }
        \label{mylabel}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```